# Check AD users' network share mapping with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I tried using net use, net share, among others - none of which return the expected output. So instead, I'm modifying a script I found to see which network drives/shares are mapped to a user the script is pushed to. Then I go to my log file, look at the data, and determine if the account is set up properly. Here's the current script:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -computer $env:COMPUTERNAME | select name, providername
Out-File -filepath "\\*UNC filepath*\Mapped_Drives_$env:USERNAME$(get-date -Format _MM-dd-yy" @ "HH.mm.ss" "tt).txt"
```

When I run it, the log file returns empty and I'm not sure why. I changed "Out-File -filepath" to "Start-Transcript" which isn't working the way I want it to either (with too much verbose output). It outputs fine in my PowerShell ISE with all the proper shares listed, but doesn't work when I navigate to the logged output. What am I missing?

Comment: Why would there be anything in the logfile? Your `Get-WmiObject` command and your `Out-File` are not connected. Try piping the one into the other.

Comment: @Tomalak That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pipe the output into the logfile

```
$logfile = "\\*UNC filepath*\Mapped_Drives_$env:USERNAME$(get-date -Format _MM-dd-yy" @ "HH.mm.ss" "tt).txt"

Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select name, providername | Out-File $logfile
```

On a more general note I'd use the commands to fix the mapped drives right there and then, instead of just writing them to a logfile for later inspection.